# while read loop question

Tags: shell-script

Found in a script

```
{while read logfilename rest

do

LogFileSize=`wc -c $logfilename | awk '{print $1}'`

....

..........

done < /tmp/filelist
}
```

I'm not sure what `rest` is, can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 1):

In a `while read` loop:

> The line is split into fields as with word
>       splitting, and the first word is assigned to the first NAME, the second
>       word to the second NAME, and so on, with **any leftover words assigned to
>       the last NAME**.

This means if your input is something like:

```
name1
name2 foo
name3
```

And you were only doing:

```
while read logfilename
```

On the second iteration your `logfilename` variable would be set to `'name2 foo'`.

Therefore it is relatively common practice for people to create a "trash" variable to collect any potential unwanted input you may encounter.  This variable likely wont be used in the script but is just there to ensure `logfilename` never gets bad data.

Comment: Also, the calculation of the length of the log could be done with `stat -c %s "$logfilename"` (on Linux) without having to read the whole log with `wc`. And I don't see a reason to run the `while` loop in a `{ ...; }` in the code provided.

Comment: Side note: `Rest` would translate to `remain`, `tail`, `leftovers` from German, which could be the origin of the confusion here.

Comment: @Fiximan: In english I just thought of it as "the rest". Which means roughly the same thing.